# Getting text in the correct format for use with spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I'm struggling to prepare my text data in the most suitable format for spacy.
I have created a [CSV file - DOWNLOAD HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xramcw9xerg73ug/test_line_breaks.csv?dl=0) which shows how my raw text data is structured. 
If you opened this in excel you would see that each cell is a document however the 3rd document contains line breaks, but i do not want a new line within a document to be parsed as a new document, only a new cell to represent the new document.

if I import the CSV to a pandasDF the resulting DF retains the structure that I want, but spacy will not work directly from this DF

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_line_breaks.csv')
```

I need to get this data into a format usable by spacy so that it recognises new documents correctly and doesnt interpret new lines within a document as a new document.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What errors are you encountering? Pandas should be more than capable of handling such simple CSV...

Comment: @zwer I'm not getting errors when using pandas, its just that spacy is not designed to work with data frames. This question is more about getting the data from my resulting pandas data frame into a format which works with spacy.

Comment: @Tom if this is about going from pandas to spacy, try providing a minimal example that reproduces the problem. It is unclear at the moment if this problem is the result of the data in the CSV or that the data comes from pandas.

Comment: I have found a solution for this.
By by replacing line break characters in the original CSV with a space and then reading in the CSV 
code'text = open('test_line_breaks.csv').read()
This gets the data into python in a form which is accepted by spacy.